# Visual Studio 2010 extension get selected text

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, mef, visual-studio-addins

I'm writing my own extension. I've created a toolbar button. The template I used was "Visual Studio Package" and there was an option during the wizard to create a command button (or something like that)

So the button shows up, but I can't work out how to get the current document or the selected text within the document.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to approach it:

1. Handle the button globally and use `DTE` to get the current document ([`DTE.ActiveDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte._dte.activedocument.aspx)) and selected text (`((TextDocument)activeDoc).Selection.Text`).  You can get the top-level `DTE` object in your package by writing: `DTE dte = GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;`  Note that the active document may be `null`.
2. Create a command handler at the editor level to handle the given command.  The Align Assignments extension I wrote ([source](http://github.com/noahric/alignassignments)) is an example of this.  Here's what the [command filter](http://github.com/NoahRic/AlignAssignments/blob/master/CommandFilter.cs) looks like.

Comment: Thanks, the DTE dte = GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE; was exactly what I was after, I was playing around with the GetService. Is there any resource which lists everything you can pass in to it? and what they all do?

Comment: One trick is to look for interfaces like `SDTE`; the "S" means "service", and is used as the key for objects stuck in the service provider.  Take a look at [this namespace on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164288.aspx) (scroll the page down until you find the interfaces that start with `SVs`).

Comment: ...I should also mention: each of these maps to *at least* one interface, though some can map to many.  For example, `SVsUIShell` maps to `IVsUIShell`, `IVsUIShell2`...through 4.

Comment: It should be noted that `DTE` only works if there is a `using EnvDTE;` in the header. Same holds true for the `EnvDTE.TextSelection` and other stuff.